# Zoom - required permissions?

Tags: privacy, zoom-meeting

I just installed zoom and I would prefer to only give the app access to the minimum of data. Anyone who can help identify what permissions (see attached list) besides "play/record audio" and "use camera", are necessary and which ones are not?

[List of permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/plgak.png)

Comment: "Necessary" is a subjective term. The permissions speak for themselves, and it is up to you to decide what still works for you.

Comment: I think - if you want to be cautious - a reasonable approach  would be - grant the permissions you know it will need (eg camera, network, audio) … then try disabling the others one by one and check what functionality - if any - is noticeably lost.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I've now turned everything off but play/rec+audio+cam - I'll see how that works...

Comment: Did you use `sudo` when installing Zoom? I think this gives the install script a permission to do and access anything it likes on your computer, so I don't understand how setting permissions after the installation help with security.